# Scrollable Textview Not working

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, scrollview

I am trying to make a scrollable TextView where the user can scroll the updates.

[image]

I tried this:

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text=""
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/updateText"
    android:background="#ce000000"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:textSize="13sp" />
```

and the code:

```
text.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
text.setText(updates.get(position).getUpdateText());
```

Yet it doesn't work properly.

It is laggy. Sometimes it works, but most of the time it doesn't.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried just putting the `TextView` inside a `ScrollView`?

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe Yes i did but it is still laggy

Answer (score 2):

Set the below attributes to your TextView

```
android:maxLines = "20" // any number
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

Also setMovementMethod() -

```
 text.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: i don't mean its not working . But it is too laggy it takes about 5-7 scrolls and with a certain angle to do 1 scroll

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a ScrollView and then put inside this TextView.

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text=""
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/updateText"
    android:background="#ce000000"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:textSize="13sp" />
```